# How to convert array of byte to original file (to provide download of file)

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database

I m using Opendialogbox to read the file. Then stored the file in byte[] array.

file --> byte []
byte[] --> stored on SQL AZure in varbinary(max) field.

Here is my code:

```
      OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if ((bool)ofd.ShowDialog())
        {
             FileStream fileStream = ofd.File.OpenRead());

              byte[]  buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
               int read = 0;                             
            using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
            {
                do
                {
                    read = binaryReader.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
                    // Stored the File in byte[] Array buffer
                } while (read > 0);
            }

        }
```

Now I want to convert this byte array to the original file (like .doc,.txt,jpeg). i know the extension in which file is to be convert.

SQL AZure  ---> byte[]     // done
 byte[]   ---> to original file.  // Problem

Please give solution to download the file.

Comment: Your code isn't uploading the file anywhere. If you are uploading the file to SQL Azure then just read byte[] using SQL Azure API and write to target stream (file or response etc)

Comment: i want to download the file from byte[] array.

Comment: When i do System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("urfile.jpeg", buffer). it gives error File operation not permitted. Access to path urfile.jpeg' is denied –

Comment: The access error is because the process doesn't have permission to write the file. Do you know under which user account the code is running?

Comment: Yes i know. is it possible to set the permissions. But tomorrow this code may run on different account then what would be done.

Comment: You should write this file to some specific directory, and this directory path should be picked from configuration file and making sure that the user account under which the application is running has the permission to this directory would be a deployment step

Comment: Then you should write the file to temp directory. You can get temp dir from System.IO.Path.GetTempPath method

Answer (score 1):

One way - not necessarily the best - is as follows:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(theBytes)) 
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(string.Format("C:\\tempfile.{0}", theExtension))) 
    {
        ms.WriteTo(fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is giving me same error --    File operation not permitted. Access to path 'C:\nwFile.jpeg' is denied

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace FileSaveDialogDemo  
{  

public partial class MainPage : UserControl  
{ 
    #region Fields  
    SaveFileDialog dialog= new SaveFileDialog(); 
    #endregion  

    #region Constructors  
    public MainPage()  
    {  
        InitializeComponent();  
        this.dialog = new SaveFileDialog();  
        try 
        {  
            this.dialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";  
            this.dialog.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|Log Files|*.log|All Files|*.*";  
            this.dialog.FilterIndex = 2;  
        }  
        catch ( Exception ex )  
        {  
            this.tblError.Text = "Error configuring SaveFileDialog: " + ex.Message;  
        }  
    } 
    #endregion  

    private void btnSaveFile_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )  
    {  
        bool? dialogResult = this.dialog.ShowDialog();  

        if ( dialogResult == true )  
        {  
            try 
            {  
               byte[] fileBytes; // your varbinary file from database
               using (Stream fs = (Stream)dialog.OpenFile())
                {
                fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
                lblMsg.Content = "File successfully saved!";
               }   

            }  
            catch ( Exception ex )  
            {  
                this.tblError.Text = "Error calling service: " + ex.Message; 
            }  
        }  
    }  // End of Function
 }// End of MainPage class

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue you have has probably nothing to do with saving a binary file; it is more likely a basic security issue. Try saving to a path on which you have programmatic write access. For example, try saving to your My Documents directory instead of C:. Try using the Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration like this, and append the file name + extension.

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)

You have a number of other ways to work around this issue, including starting Visual Studio in Elevated Mode (run as Administrator), and/or allow "Everyone" write access to your C:\ drive. But I wouldn't recommend these techniques necessarily; consider saving to a folder where the security settings are lower than c:\, such as My Documents.